# Passing variable to postgresql query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

In my Ruby on Rails app I'm using blazer gem(https://github.com/ankane/blazer). I have the following query there:

```
select id from slide_results where tags @> '[{tag}]';
```

When I submit some text via text input it produces following query:

```
select id from slide_results where tags @> '['asd']';
```

This query doesn't work, that's because of this single quotes around 'asd'. How can I change those single quotes to double quotes?

Comment: change your single quotes around "[{tag}]" instead?

Comment: I think you should have query like select id from slide_results where tags @> '{tag}'; Can you please check?